# Pusher sending event is not showing in console

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4, pusher

I am trying to show pusher sending event for showing in my console. But it giving empty in my console.though send info. from my browser to pusher is working, but sending event from pusher is not working.
[image]

i have filled up all info in my laravel project file, like PUSHER_APP_ID,PUSHER_APP_KEY etc, but sending from browser is working, but receiving event from pusher is not working.any help....

Comment: It's very hard to understand the problem you're having from the description you've provided. If you were to provide some snippets of your code (removing any sensitive data like keys/secrets etc) it might be easier for people to help :)

Comment: all coding is ok, key, id other things, but problem in console that not showing received message from pusher, thanks

Comment: What do you mean `but sending from browser is working` ?

Comment: sending message with send method